# Abstract Class Error In C++ SFML

Tags: c++, abstract-class, sfml

Hello all I though it would be fun exercise to try to make a Sierpinski Triangle and I am having an issue with this abstract class error that I can't seem to figure out. When I try to make a SierpinskiTri "SierpinskiTri sierpinskiii;" object and then draw it to the window "window.draw(sierpinskiii);" i get an error on that object saying it is an abstract class

```
class SierpinskiTri : public sf::Drawable{
public :

SierpinskiTri(sf::RenderWindow &window):m_window(window) {
    //filledTriangle(300, 400, 300);
    sierpinski(3 ,300, 0,300);
     }

virtual void sierpinski(int n, double x, double y, double s){

        filledTriangle(x, y, s);
        sierpinski(n-1, x - s/2, y, s/2);
        sierpinski(n-1, x + s/2, y, s/2);
        sierpinski(n-1, x, y+sqrt(3)/2*s, s/2);

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}


virtual void filledTriangle(float x, float y, float s){
    float* xl = new float[4];
    xl[0] = x - s/2; xl[1]= x + s/2;  xl[2]  = x; xl[3] = x-s/2;
    float* yl = new float[4];
    yl[0] = sqrt(3)/2*s+y; yl[1] = yl[0]; yl[2] = y; yl[3] = yl[0];

    draw(xl,yl,m_window);

}
private:
sf::RenderWindow &m_window;

virtual void draw(float xl[],float yl[],sf::RenderWindow &window) const {

sf::VertexArray triangle(sf::Triangles, 3);

 triangle[0].position = sf::Vector2f(xl[0],yl[1]);
 triangle[0].color = sf::Color::Blue;  
 triangle[1].position = sf::Vector2f(xl[1],yl[1]);
 triangle[1].color = sf::Color::Red;
 triangle[2].position = sf::Vector2f(xl[2],xl[2]);
 triangle[2].color = sf::Color::White;
 window.draw(triangle);
}


};
```

Answer (score 3):

When you inherit from [`Drawable`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php):

```
class SierpinskiTri : public sf::Drawable { .. };
```

you also inherit all of its methods, one of which is:

```
virtual void draw (RenderTarget &target, RenderStates states) const = 0;
```

You are not providing an implementation of `draw`, so your `SierpinksiTri` class is also an abstract class and you cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

The solution is to provide an implementation for `draw()`.

Answer (score 2):

By [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) you have to override that function:

```
virtual void sf::Drawable::draw( RenderTarget& target
                               , RenderStates states ) const;
```

You have written that function:

```
virtual void draw( float xl[]
                 , float yl[]
                 , sf::RenderWindow &window ) const;
```

As result your derived class is abstract like compiler tells. In order to override you need to match the signature of virtual function correctly.